# How to convert fb2 into pdf in linux via terminal?

Tags: linux, terminal, file-conversion

How I can convert *fb2* into *pdf* in linux via terminal ?

Answer (score 3):

Via soffice : *If Libreoffice already installed*

```
soffice --headless --convert-to pdf book.fb2
```

Answer (score 1):

I have never used it, but you can try `pandoc`.

Install `pandoc`, go where your .fb2 file is and run `pandoc file.fb2 -o file.pdf`. It should generate .pdf file which is just converted .fb2 file.

More info about `pandoc` [here](http://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html). It can convert all sorts of files, check it out.

Comment: can you update with some details about how to handle exceptions like latex-based characters?